# Phaser 3 physics group with circle

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm fairly new to Phaser, and am following this tutorial: https://www.codecaptain.io/blog/game-development/shooting-bullets-phaser-3-using-arcade-physics-groups/696

Except, that instead of the `Laser` being a `Sprite`, I just want it to be a simple circle, so I tried the following;

```
export class Laser extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body {
    constructor(scene: Phaser.Scene, x: number, y: number) {
        const c = new Phaser.GameObjects.Ellipse(scene, x, y, 25, 25, 0x00ff00);

        super(scene.physics.world, c);
    }
}
```

This just throws the following error `Uncaught TypeError: child.addToDisplayList is not a function`.

Am I missing something fairly fundamental here? I can only seem to be able to use `Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Sprite` or `Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Image`. Is it not possible to just have a physics object that consist of multiple rectangles or circles?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you would just have to add the *"Laser"* `GameObject` to the `scene` and than add the `GameObject` to the *physics world*, for it to work.

You would only have to make a few minor tweaks for it to work, as intended.

***(Updated Code)* Here is a short runable demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class Laser extends Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body {
    constructor(scene, x, y) {
        
        // add object to the scene, so that it can be displayed
        const c = scene.add.ellipse( x, y, 25, 25, 0x00ff00);
        
        // create the actual body
        super(scene.physics.world, c);
        
        // add Body to world
        scene.physics.add.existing(c)
    }
}

class Laser2 extends Phaser.GameObjects.Ellipse {
    constructor(scene, x, y) {
        super(scene, x, y, 25, 25, 0xff0000);
        
        //give the GameObject a Physics body
        scene.physics.add.existing(this)
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 100 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {
    this.add.text(10,10, 'Falling balls- red are from a Group')
        .setScale(1.5)
        .setOrigin(0)
        .setStyle({fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial'});

    // create a laser
    let laser = new Laser(this, 50, 50)
    
    // create second  laser with a phaser group
    let group = this.physics.add.group({  classType: Laser2});
    
    group.createMultiple({max: 30})
      
    let groupBall = group.create(150, 10)
    
    // Or simply like this
    // groupBall.body.setVelocityY (150)
    groupBall.body.setVelocity(0, 150)
    
    let groupBall2 = group.create(200, 10)
    
    groupBall2.body.setVelocityY(200)
      
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> ***Warning:** if you are not using a `sprite` or an `image`, and you are using a *physics-group* be careful, because not all properties of the group object can be used. Check the [documentaiton](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.GameObjects.Group.html#.GroupCreateConfig__anchor) to be on the save side.*

Comment: While the example works, this does not seem to work in the context of the tutorial, which is using `Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Group`.

Comment: @Mike well I didn't read the tutorial, I just answered your question. :) That said I updated my answer with a version, that can work with a phaser group _(ofcourse it depends on your usage)_.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm super new to this, so wanted to stick to the tutorial as much as I could. With the `Laser2` example, how could I then set the velocity? I don't seem to have `setVelocityY` available on `Phaser.GameObjects.Ellipse`.

Comment: @Mike you can get the velocity from the the attached `body` property. this property is attached to the `gameObject` after it was added to the physics world _( on `scene.physics.add.existing(this)`)_. I updated the example